# Practice with “en quoi”

Tags: adverbes, locutions

Is this sentence correct:

- En quoi ma vie serait-elle différente si j’étais né plus tard dans l’année ?

To mean “how would my life be different if I’d been born later in the year?”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is correct and is the translation of the English.

"In what way" or "to what extent" instead of "how" is another possibility found by DeepL.